# Comparing two result lines generated with fprintf before writing them to file

Tags: c++, c, printf

I have a c++ commandline program that writes a list of data to file as part of a validation process like this:

```
fprintf(code,"%s\t%s\t%5.3f\t%5.3f\t%5.3f\t\n", the_five_variables_the_data_comes_from
```

This happens in a for loop and I'd like to check programatically if two subsequent lines match. My question is what's the best way to do this and what does a noob need to know to implement it (just saying don't assume too much preknowledge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to format into an intermediate string before writing it to the file. Keep each iteration stored in a 'previous' variable and compare it against current.

Something like this:

```
char previous[SIZE];
*previous = '\0';

for (...)
{
    char buffer[SIZE];
    sprintf(buffer, "...", ...);
    if (strcmp(previous, buffer) == 0)
        // Do something.

    strcpy(previous, buffer);
    fputs(buffer, file);
}
```

Comment: Or if he is using C++, he may want to give stringstream + fstream a try; not a C++ nazi, it's just that C.O. said c++.

Answer (score 2):

```
ofstream foo("output.txt");
string out, temp;
...loop....
{
    out = variable1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5;
    if(out == temp)
         ...match...
    foo << out;
    temp = out;

}
foo.close();
```